Fill the content by extending a controls in SAPUI5
I'm extending a OverflowToolbar and I want to fill the aggregation "content" when I define the metadata.
I tried to put the "content" in the aggregations of the toolbar like this:
metadata: {
  properties: {
    style: {
      type: "string",
      defaultValue: "Clear",
    },
  },
  aggregations: {
    content: { singleName: "content" },
  },
},

init: function () {
  OverflowToolbar.prototype.init.call(this);

  this.setAggregation("content", new sap.ui.core.Control());
},

renderer: function (oRm, oToolbar) {
  sap.m.OverflowToolbarRenderer.render(oRm, oToolbar);
},

but I have this error:

Uncaught (in promise) 
Error: Aggregation 'content' of Element testenvironment.controls.Paginator#__paginator0 used with wrong cardinality (declared as 0..n)


Does anyone know how I can define the content in the metadata and then set the aggregation?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

To avoid any xy problem: could you please elaborate on why you'd like to extend the standard sap.m.OverflowToolbar in the first place? What are you trying to achieve by extending the toolbar?

If you are extending the OverflowToolbar you don't need to define a content aggregation since it already exists on the original control. If you want to define a default content for your extention, just call .addContent with your default controls on the init method of your extension. Additionally, although on the API documentation it says that content aggregation accepts sap.ui.core.Control, it normally means the use of any control that extends sap.ui.core.Control (e.g. Text, Input, Button, etc...). sap.ui.core.Control object won't give you any functionality

According to the documentation OverflowToolbar can take only a certain number of controls as its content and sap.ui.core.Control is not among them.
Regarding adding some content: why don't you use the addContent method?
